# OpenLDAP rewrite attribute values when proxying

Tags: active-directory, rewrite, openldap

I seem to struggle with the concept of rewrite using the RWM module. The examples don't really seem to tell me a lot BUT I don't claim to be an LDAP expert as well

What I want to achieve is "simple", I want to proxy between an ActiveDirectory using OpenLDAP as proxy. This I've managed and seems to work. As an extension, I'd like to rewrite a value. E.g. field mifareUid in AD is 123456 but I'd like to rewrite this to 563412 if possible.

I see that there are some rewrite capabilities available, but it always seems to discuss DNs, which I'm unsure if this is the case (again, no LDAP expert)

Is it possible at all? Or will this require a custom overlay module?